# Avoid Verification code for Salesforce Login

Tags: community

How to avoid Entering verification code for salesforce Login. I already tried solutions of Firefox profile and Entering IP addresses.

Used below code for Firefox profile.

```
ProfilesIni allProfiles = new ProfilesIni();

FirefoxProfile profile = allProfiles.getProfile("selenium");

WebDriver driver = FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Answer (score 3):

Verification codes are part of Salesforce security measures. You can't avoid them unless you change your org's security settings.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I condone this but I think if you added Trusted IP Ranges you can bypass the verification.  Ideally you will have a static IP Address but otherwise you can set the range to `0.0.0.0 to 1.255.255.255`

which means all users will bypass computer activiation/verification.  I haven't done this myself but you can do it by navigating:

> Setup > Security Controls > Network Access.

If you are unsure of your IP address, check the login history or google "what's my IP".

Since 2016 Salesforce uses the local browser to cache logins.  This means if your browser blocks or removes user data you will be repeatedly asked to verify when logging in.