# Is Salesforce Verification Code Challenge a kind of Two-Factor Authentication?

Tags: authentication, two-factor-authentication

I am wondering if the Verification Code Challenge users usually get upon logging in their Salesforce Org can be considered as a kind of Two-Factor Authentication. The reason why I am asking this question is that I couldn't find any explanation re- the Verification Code Challenge, except in this **[post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/192231/avoid-verification-code-for-salesforce-login)**:

> Verification codes are part of Salesforce security measures.

From the [Salesforce Two-Factor Authentication](https://trust.salesforce.com/static/images/2fa/Salesforce_2FA_FAQ.pdf) document I can assume that this is true. I have my Password (first factor), and I have my email address (second factor) to which Salesforce sends a verification code. Still I'd like to verify my thoughts with community.

Comment: Your assumptions are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is Salesforce Verification Code Challenge a kind of Two-Factor Authentication?

Yes - your assumption is correct.

Also known as a Two-step verification (which is exactly waht it does).

I will list a couple of them here below:

- SMS
- Authenticator App
- Push-based
- Security Keys
- List item

Additionally, here is a 'site validator' that allows you to know what services use
[Two Factor Auth (2FA)](https://twofactorauth.org/).
Interestingly enought, Salesfsorce is on the list, and provides some of the supported 2FA methods
[image]